# SETNX and REDIS cluster

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

Does SETNX work properly in REDIS cluster? or it is meant to be work only in single instance REDIS?

Is there a official documentation regarding this? Official doc does say that it is discouraged to use for locking in favor of distributed locking.

Answer (score 0):

`SETNX` is fully supported by any Redis topology, including stand-alone and cluster. The [official docs](https://redis.io/commands/setnx/) says the suggested locking pattern mentioned there is discouraged, not the command itself:

> [...] The following pattern is discouraged in favor of the Redlock algorithm which is only a bit more complex to implement, but offers better guarantees and is fault tolerant.
> [...]